# What are the annual conferences to develop the LaTeX?

Tags: latex3

What, where and when annual conferences are held to develop the LaTeX?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The major TeX yearly TeX conferences are

- The TUG meeting (http://tug.org/tug2021/ is the next): As TUG is both the international TeX group and also the US national group, the meeting is held
  most often in the US but does move around. (For 2020 and 2021, COVID-19 has meant it is taking place virtually)
- The BachoTeX meeting (http://www.gust.org.pl/bachotex) in Poland
- The ConTeXt user meeting (https://meeting.contextgarden.net/), which takes place in Europe
- The DANTE Spring and Autumn meetings (https://www.dante.de/): formally for the German user group
- The GuIT annual meeting (https://www.guitex.org/home/meeting?lang=en): again, formally a national user meeting (Italian users)

---

Worth adding is that these are not strictly developer meetings: the topics vary widely.

Comment: There are other national meetings, but the ones I've highlighted here are the largest I'm aware of. For example, the UK group tend to get only around a dozen people at most (we book a 'dungeon' for the purpose).

Comment: Re Joseph: https://xkcd.com/2347/